# Proof check for "every neighbourhood is an open set"

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I have been goind through Rudin for the past month and I have arrived at this theorem in the topology chapter. Now I understand Rudin's proof but I was trying to come up with my own and I am not sure if it is correct or not.

**Theorem**: Every neighbourhood is an open set.

**Proof**: Suppose that there exists a neighbourhood $N$ of $p$ that is not open. Then there exists a point $q$ in $N$ that is not an interior point of $N$. Then any neighbourhood $N_q$ of $q$ is not included in $N$. Choose $N_q$ such that $p$ is in $N_q$. Since $N_q$ is not in $N$, then $p$ is not in in $N$. Contradiction.

I have attached an image showing what I had in mind when I wrote this.

[The gray edge boundary means that it's not included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQQW9.png)

Comment: What is your definition of a neighbourhood?

Comment: A neighbourhood of a point p is a set N consisting of all points q such that d(p, q) < r, where r>0.

Comment: Oke, then what is your definition of an open set?

Comment: A set is open if every point of that set is an interior point of that set. And a point p is interior of E if there is a neighbourhood N of p such that N is in E.

Comment: You should probably include this in the question, since they are equivalent but non-standard definitions.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit it right now

Comment: Usually people define what you call a "neighborhood" as an "open ball". It is then a non-tautological theorem that "open balls are open". More commonly a neighborhood of a point is a set containing an open set which in turn contains that point.

Comment: @Ian usually what OP calls neighborhoods are just defined to be the basis for the topology; this is just the definition of the topology on a metric space. In this case the statement is tautological. Defining what an open set is in terms of interior points is in my opinion very strange and not very clear...

Comment: @user2520938 I've never heard $\{ q : d(p,q)<r \}$ called anything but an open ball. And under this definition, plus "an open set in a metric space is any set which contains an open ball around each of its points", "open balls are open sets" is not tautological. If instead you say "the topology on a metric space is the one generated by the open balls", then "open balls are open sets" is tautological. But in my experience this approach is unusual, especially in introductory references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your proof is incorrect.  There is a problem with your statement: "Since $N_q$ is not in $N$, then $p$ is not in $N$".

It is true that $N_q$ is not a subset of $N$, but it is certainly possible that some elements (points) of $N_q$ are also elements of $N$.

Comment: You are right, I see my error now. Thank you.